# java socket can't send message using BufferedWriter

Tags: java

I am trying to use `BufferedWriter` to send a message to the server from the client or server to client. However nothing will send, but it will listen if you send a message to it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I think the problem is from here.

```
ActionListener buttonActive= new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                messageTextArea.append(textMessage.getText()+ "\n");
                sendText = textMessage.getText();
            }
        };
        sendButton.addActionListener(buttonActive);

    private void startSending(){

        SwingWorker <Void, Void> sendingThread = new SwingWorker <Void, Void>(){
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
                while(connected){
                    writer.write(sendText);
                    writer.flush();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        sendingThread.execute();
    }
```

@trashgod and @madProgrammer gave me a solution using printWriter which works but I want me to make a few more version using `BufferedWriter`+`BufferedReader`, `OutputStream+ InputStream` and `BufferedWriter`+`PrintWriter`, however i want to make the `BufferedWriter`+`BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does indeed send data. Maybe the client is calling `readLine()`? As you aren't sending a line terminator, it will block forever.

But your code doesn't make much sense. Writing the same text in a loop can't be what you intended. And there is no such thing as a `PrintReader`.

Comment: sorry i just saw printWriter and assume there was one lol. does it not keep the connection running if i keep it in the loop? or maybe i am over thinking it i'll change it and see if that is sends. But I do remember reading up online that it says I should have 2 threads one to listen and one to send

Comment: @user62927 Certainly you can use two threads, but that doesn't mean the sending thread should just keep spinning in a send loop. It should send when there is something to send.

Comment: i tried that early with the an if statment if(sendText=!null) but that didnt work. but yeah your right the client is calling the readline(); is the the line terminator writer.newline()?